# Sphinx Partial Word Searching with Underscored Titles.

Tags: sphinx

Currently trying to use Sphinx to search through medicine names, and because of the way the US structure medical names its all medicine_type in the database, and there's no way of changing that going forward.

If for instance I search medicine_type Sphinx will find it easily, but if I type just the medicine name to bring up all types of that medicine, it won't.

I've tried enabling expand_keywords = 1 to no avail.

Is there anything I can do to make Sphinx do what I need it to?

Answer (score 0):

Well the *default* `charset_table` includes underscore as a word character

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-charset-table

```
# default are English and Russian letters
charset_table = 0..9, A..Z->a..z, _, a..z, \
    U+410..U+42F->U+430..U+44F, U+430..U+44F, U+401->U+451, U+451
```

A simple solution, might just be to remove it from charset table (ie define `charset_table` explicitly without `_` in the list!)

```
# custom charset without understore
charset_table = 0..9, A..Z->a..z, a..z, \
    U+410..U+42F->U+430..U+44F, U+430..U+44F, U+401->U+451, U+451
```

... then underscore would be taken a word *separator* (like spaces) and mean words would match.

*(could also maybe remove some of the russian chars if don't need them. And investigate if other letters want to index)*

---

Might also at least want to consider `blend_chars`
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-blend-chars
although in this situation don't think it particularly helps.

Comment: I'm not sure reading the docu that I understand how the charset table works, is there an example?

Comment: Added an explicit example to post.