# Stopword "_" in sphinx

Tags: sphinx

I have records that come in as `LastName_FirstName` e.g. `Smith_Bob` so am unable to search for `Smith` or `Bob` independently.  I tried add ing `_` to my stopwords.txt file and re-rotating to no avail. Is there another way to force `_` to be ignored?

Comment: By some massive coincidence, almost the exact same question was only asked yesterday! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44045088/sphinx-partial-word-searching-with-underscored-titles

Comment: http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/conf-blend-chars.html